# It's possible save a html5 component in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

No doubt that could be a very bad practice though. However I have the restlessness that if is possible to do something like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
 // Child components
 ....
</div>
```

Then:

```
const cvs = sessionStorage.setItem('componentsInCache', document.querySelector('#parent'));

document.getElementById('anotherId').innerHTML = cvs;
```

Is there a way to make possible something similar?

Comment: Yeah, but you would have to stringify all the HTMLElement objects and then rehydrate them using their explicit tagNames and iterate/assign all the other properties associated with them.

Comment: Storage only stores strings. What is your use case?